# How you should retrieve google plus +1 count for an url?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-plus-one

Using the rpc method:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
$curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
echo intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
```

or using the +1 button scrapping method?

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
$result = file_get_contents('https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url='.urlencode($url));
preg_match( '/window\.__SSR = {c: ([\d]+)/', $result, $matches );

echo (isset($matches[0])) ? (int) str_replace('window.__SSR = {c:', '', $matches[0]) : 0;
```

Having an explanation of differences or possible side effects would be great.

Note: Both methods works as 2014/04/05.

Answer (score 1):

Given that neither are official / supported by Google, I'd propably use the first method and fallback to the second in case that fails. The second method is more error-prone, since you're parsing source code that can change at any time (not that calling a service you're not supposed to be calling is any better, but apparently there are no other options).